# Check if an Element is deleted from list

Tags: java

simply, I want to check if an Element is deleted from a list, and than do some actions after that. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
(...)
private CollectionUtils removed;    
    public void subscription() {    
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(save)) {
                System.out.println("blabla");
                JsfUtils.addTranslatedMessageToTarget(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, null, "bla");
            } else if (CollectionUtils.subtract(save, removed)){ //Check if element is deleted
                System.out.println(removed + " blablaca");
            } else {
                System.out.println("blabla");
            }

        }
```

I edited and cut some code because its for a company I work for. At subtract he suggest to cast the Collection Type on "Collection", which doesnt make any sense for me. As Exception it points out an nullpointer exception.

Thanks

Comment: Check what 'CollecionUtils.subtract' does... That is not jsf or hibernate related

Comment: Have you tried the List/Collection#contains and/or List/Collection#indexOf element ? i am not sure to understand well what you want to do.